# Removing undefined members from type

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like this:

```js
type T = {
    a: number;
    b: undefined;
};
```

As `b` property's value is undefined, I would like to be able to assign `{ a: 0 }` to a variable of this type like so:

```js
const c: T = { a: 0 };
```

But this result in error `Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'T'.`.

Is there a way to create a `RemoveUndefinedValues` generic such as:

```js
type T2 = RemoveUndefinedValues<T>; // T2 = { a: number }
```

Pretty much the way `Omit<Type, Keys>` works, but with values instead of keys?

Comment: Are you sure you want to **remove** the key and not just **make it optional**?

Comment: @vera. Having `T2 = { a: number; b?: undefined }` would be fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **remove** the key, there's two ways we could go about it. We could either omit the undefined keys, or pick only the defined keys.

Here are the utility types for those:

```
type DefinedKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? never : K }[keyof T];

// Can also be written as Exclude<keyof T, DefinedKeys<T>>
type UndefinedKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

And then

```
type MethodOne = Pick<T, DefinedKeys<T>>;
//   ^? { a: number }
type MethodTwo = Omit<T, UndefinedKeys<T>>;
//   ^? { a: number }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFTUCGAuKAdgK4C2ARhAE4Dc6WUZ+RBAJhAGYCWBELtaAX37pQkKABEO3XgGkIIAM4AeGAD4EyKAG0ZUblADW8gPbtYAXXwwd5qBAAewCKwVRmbLjxZQA-IQgAblRQ+LoCWkYgphbCaKLQAKqsUl5yiirqiEjauvqR0TCWsDZ2js4sru4pvL5Quvg8QZRQ4flmhbHxUACyEMAAFsYsAPI8GgAKnADGBioANBLVLGnKaqr8APQbWAB6PiLg0L0DQzAA7sYawyScwPNQSR7Sy-KrquvoW7v7aEA)

---

If you want to **make it optional**, then you can do so with an intersection of mapped types using the two utilities above:

```
type MakeUndefinedOptional<T> = ({
    [K in DefinedKeys<T>]: T[K];
} & {
    [K in UndefinedKeys<T>]?: T[K];
}) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never; // Only for show

type MethodThree = MakeUndefinedOptional<T>;
//   ^? { a: number; b?: undefined }
```

The extra `extends infer O` is done because TS will not show the underlying resulting type. This forces TS to "simplify" and expand the result in full.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXz5Qm)